# Is it possible to make a bash function in which the return values can be given variables?

Tags: bash

on an enhanced ls command, I'd like to have each returned item be given a number, so I can `cd ${1}` instead of manually typing the desired dirname

```
/folder $ ls
tabler
new_project
notes
basicwebsite
/folder $
```

something like `cd -1` instead of `cd basicwebsite`

Comment: You can use the `set` built-in to set the positional arguments. But the problem is that each function scope has its own positional arguments, so doing it in the function won't affect the main shell process.

Comment: You could put them in an array, then use `cd ${a[1]}`